# В визуальном редакторе неправильно отображаются материальные карточки на API 19

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

После сегодняшнего обновления SDK Tools до версии 24 (до этого стояла 23 версия) при выборе API 19 CardView отображаются темно-серого цвета и выдается предупреждение при рендеринге:

[image: Rendering problems]

До обновления все отображалось нормально на всех версиях API.
Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

У вас два пути:

1. Отказаться от использования предпросмоторщика, ибо он не нужен и тестировать на эмуляторе/девайсе. Это правильный путь.
2. Откатиться на старую версию, ту, где у вас работало и делать так всё время при выходе к-л обновлений. Это неправильный путь.

Comment: @ИгорьМахов, это очень странно. Попробуйте эмулятор Genymotion

Comment: Кстати на эмуляторе и на устройстве стало отображаться все нормально, а на Preview нет. Вот это действительно странною

Comment: @ИгорьМахов, как раз таки это и нормально. Превью студии - багованная и бесполезная в 99% случаев фича. В ней всегда будут проблемы. Большинство никогда им не пользовались и чувствовали себя прекрасно. Это из-за того, что очень сложно так его реализовать, чтоб он все нюансы учитывал.